# String.format has no effect

Tags: c#, .net, xml, filestream

The code executes without any error, but the {0} and {1} aren't replaced by the values declared in the String.Format

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(xmlFile.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fs);

 string docStrXml = doc.InnerXml.ToString();
 String.Format(docStrXml, newVersion.ToString(), oldVersion.ToString());

 triggerDocument.LoadXml(docStrXml);
 triggerDocument.Save(directoryPathOfNewXml + "\\" + xmlFile.Name);
```

The new file is saved without a problem. Basically, I'm opening an xml file, and I want to insert strings in the document. Here is the initial document (and also the last since it doesn't change):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Package
    source="http://localhost/Service/Master/{0}/{1}/"
    triggerseturl="http://localhost/Service/Master/{0}/{1}/client.xml">
  <File name="client_full.xml"/>
  <File name="client_half.xml"/>
</Package>
```

Comment: Please don't create XML files with string.Format or string.Concat... There are plenty of ways to create XML using XML API. Will save a lot of your and others time from asking multiple questions on "why #$#%# XML does not understand my ">" character "

Comment: @guiomie [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx), in particular [XDeclaration Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdeclaration%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable, you must assign the return value of string.Format to another variable.

It will have the new string with the inserted values.

```
docStrXml = String.Format(docStrXml, newVersion.ToString(), oldVersion.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to replace the value in `docStrXml` with the new value:

```
docStrXml = String.Format(docStrXml, newVersion.ToString(), oldVersion.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

The String.Format method returns a string based on the string argument passed [docStrXml], but doesn't operate directly on it. You'll need to assign the return value to a variable, in this case the same one you pass to the method. Modify your code to this:

```
docStrXml = String.Format(docStrXml, newVersion.ToString(), oldVersion.ToString());
```

and you should be good to go.